# How to create a simple form in the base html template django

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I have a Django app that contains multiple pages. Like the menu or footer, some elements are repeated in all of these pages, so I created a base template and added these duplicated codes.
Now I want to have a form above the footer in the base template. But I don't know how to make it work.
Should I make a view that returns the base.html? How can I inherit this form on every page of the website?
Please guide me; I'm in a bit of a pickle!

this is my context_processor :

```
def base_forms(request):
    return {       
        'info_form': BasedContactForm()
    }
```

and this is my base.html: I extend it in all other pages:

```
<form method="post" action="">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ info_form }}
   </form>
```

and this is my Blog app views:

```
def base_info_form(request):
 if request.method == 'POST':
    info_form = BaseContactForm(request.POST)
    if info_form.is_valid():
        info_form.save()
        return redirect('Home-Page')
    else:
        info_form = BaseContactForm()
    return render(request, '', {'info_form': info_form})
```

Comment: If the form truly is on every page you could add the form in a context processor https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors

Comment: Could you explain more? How am I supposed to use it?

Comment: @Sam, You can also use template tag [**`extends`** ([Django Docs)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#extends). I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add some data to global context through settings `TEMPLATES > OPTIONS > context_processors` - [Writing your own context processors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors).

And for extending templates use template tag [**`extends`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#extends)([Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#extends)).

**1. Adding variable to context**

---

Create **yourapp/context_processors.py**:

```
from django.conf import settings

from yourapp.forms import MyForm


def base_data(request):
    data = {}
    # MyForm(request.GET, user=request.user)
    data["my_form"] = MyForm()
    data["my_email"] = settings.MYEMAIL
    return data
```

And add it to `context_processors` in **settings.py**:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
           ...
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                ...
                'yourapp.context_processors.base_data',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Now you can access your this data in any template:

```
{{ my_form }}, {{ my_email }}
```

**2. Extending Templates**

---

You can also use template tag [**`extends`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#extends)([Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#extends)) to extend your templates:

```
template.html
base.html
```

In template.html, the following paths would be valid:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
<div class="container">
    Some HTML code
</div>
```

Additional info [**`TEMPLATES`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#templates)([Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#templates)) and [**`OPTIONS`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates) ([Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates)) available parameters.

**UPDATE**

---

**views.py**:

```
def contact(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BaseContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('Home-Page')
    else:
        form = BaseContactForm()
    return redirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
```

**urls.py**:

```
path('contact/', views.contact, name='contact'),
```

Comment: how do i save my form?

Comment: @Sam, you have to create a view to handel your form.

Comment: @Sam, you have to handle your `BaseContactForm` in views.py. The context_processor is only to add global data.

Comment: there. i have updated my code but when I fill the form nothing happens

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229219/discussion-between-nksm-and-sam).