# no module named 'my project name'.context_processors in django

Tags: django, django-forms

Im trying to use a form in every single page of my app. the form is in the base.html page.
this is my views.py:

```
def base_info_form(request):
 if request.method == 'POST':
    form = BaseContactForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('Help-Page')
    else:
        form = BaseContactForm()
    return render(request, '', {'form': form})


def base_forms(request):
    return {
        'info_form': BaseContactForm()
    }
```

and I added it in my settings like this:

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            ......
            'Ghoghnoos.context_processors.base_forms',
        ],
    },
},
]
```

'Ghoghnoos' is the name of my project. That view was my Blog app views.
when I refresh the browser, I get this error:
No module named 'Ghoghnoos.context_processors'
what am I doing wrong here? I've never worked with custom context_processors before.

this is my context_processors.py:

```
def base_info_form(request):
 if request.method == 'POST':
    form = BaseContactForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('Home-Page')
    else:
        form = BaseContactForm()
    return render(request, '', {'form': form})


def base_forms(request):
    return {       
        'info_form': base_info_form(request)
    }
```

and this is my base.html:
.......

```
<form method="post" action="">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ info_form }}
</form>
```

.......

Comment: what's the path to the py file containing your custom code? I suspect you are going to want something like 'Ghoghnoos.blog.base_forms.info_form` or whatever fits your file structure.

Comment: popular question today. https://stackoverflow.com/a/66372243/4872140

Answer (score 0):

Follow this path to create your base_forms :

```
Ghoghnoos(project name)
   |...
   |_ _ context_processors.py
   |_ _ settings.py
   |...
```

**Ghoghnoos(project name)/context_processors.py:**

```
def base_info_form(request):
 if request.method == 'POST':
    form = BaseContactForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('Help-Page')
    else:
        form = BaseContactForm()
    return form

def base_forms(request):
    return {         ⬇⬇⬇⬇⬇⬇⬇
        'info_form': base_info_form(request)
    }
```

Comment: And how do I save this form?

Comment: @Sam I edited my answer.Actually your error occurred in improperly given path..

Comment: I've done this, but the form won't show up on the pages. It only says 'None'.

Comment: try with `return form` instead of `return render(request, '', {'form': form})` in `base_info_form` function..

Comment: and fetch this form in your html like that : `- - - {{info_form}} - - -`

Comment: I tried your form in my machine it's work perfectly...Put your html and some other code in your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229217/discussion-between-sam-and-pradip).